# How to sign-off ("signed-off-by") a Git commit in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, git-commit

I wonder how I can add the "signed-off-by" line in a Git commit automatically within PyCharm's Commit dialog.

There are options for amending to the previous commit and changing the author of the commit, but I couldn't find an option for adding the signed-off line (`git commit -s`) on a per-commit basis.

Is it even possible or is it a missing feature?

Answer (score 15):

For anyone getting this answer in google searches, here is the solution as tested in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
echo 'no-tty' >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
echo 'use-agent' >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

Then you can:

```
git config --global format.signoff true
```

This will set git to always sign-off, and set gpg to use a gtk popup to ask for your key password when needed and avoid errors in pycharm.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: looks like `format.signoff` is not working as expected..

Comment: @Sathish make sure you are using a git version >= 1.6.3 https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d1876e9300c56f399ea2976c5831674cd9818b1

Comment: my git version is `2.24.3` @miigotu

Answer (score 6):

The IntelliJ plateform (Pycharm is based on it) doesn't seem to support Git sign-off yet ([issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65721)).

There's a similar request including [GPG signing](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110261).

Answer (score 6):

In [PyCharm 2016.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/11/pycharm-2016-3-released/) (just released) it's available as a tickbox in the commit dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to keep box ticked and add a default account to sign off on?

Comment: Available as a tick box in RubyMine commit dialog too..

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen from the linked issues, not implemented yet but then one can simply put the signing key information inside `~/.gitconfig` and run `git commit -s` from the command line, all else I do from within IDEA (WebStorm in my case).

Of course, I am looking forward when it's implemented and one doesn't have to hop outside IDEA just to have a commit signed and then go back and continue inside IDEA.