# How can I force "git commit -s" using "git commit" command?

Tags: git-commit, git-config, git

I'm looking for a way to write the `Signed-off-by:` tag automatically when I commit.

I tried configuring it through the .git/config file [(Reference)](https://harryrschwartz.com/2014/11/01/automatically-signing-your-git-commits.html). I put these lines of code:

```
[alias]
    commit = commit -s
```

This did not work. As commented below, you can not edit git's own alias (like commit).[(Reference)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias)

I also tried using the command [(Reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302034/how-to-sign-off-signed-off-by-a-git-commit-in-pycharm):
`git config --global format.signoff true`

Also had no effect. [This explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015894/git-add-signed-off-by-line-using-format-signoff-not-working/15018905#15018905) why.

I'm looking for any solution that automatically places the tag and allows me to edit the commit message directly on git, without having to use a system alias.

Comment: It is [documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias) that *"To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored."*. You should pick a new name for the alias.

Comment: `format.signoff` only matters for patch ([Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15018905/2449905)). To do what you want, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34687806/2449905).

Comment: @axiac thank you. Unfortunately I will have to use another alias.

Comment: @DanLowe That [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015894/git-add-signed-off-by-line-using-format-signoff-not-working/34687806#34687806) is not interesting. I wanted it to automatically change information like:
`Signed-off-by: $ {You_ Name} $ {your_email}`
To work for other users as well.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015894/git-add-signed-off-by-line-using-format-signoff-not-working/46536244#46536244) provides to automatically add signed-off without an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the commits hooks to achieve this
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks

> #### `prepare-commit-msg`
>
> The `prepare-commit-msg` hook is run **before** the commit message editor is fired up but **after** the default message is created.
>
> **It lets you edit the default message before the commit author sees it.**
>
> This hook takes a few parameters: the path to the file that holds the commit message so far, the type of commit, and the commit SHA-1 if this is an amended commit.
>
> This hook generally isn’t useful for normal commits; rather, it’s good for commits where the default message is auto-generated, such as templated commit messages, merge commits, squashed commits, and amended commits.
>
> You may use it in conjunction with a commit template to programmatically insert information.

Answer (score 4):

**[Edit made after last comment]**

I think if I am guessing correctly then, you cannot alias using words which are 'reserved' words for a git command.

However if you do something like this

```
[alias]
  ci = commit -s
```

Then it will do what you want it to do.

Comment: My intention was to configure directly in git, without having to appeal to the system alias.

Comment: @EliseuEgewarth, please review the answer again.

Comment: @EliseuEgewarth  Just suggesting that the question can be rephrased to say that why git alias doesn't works on some keywords.

Comment: my goal was to find an option that would change the command (`git commit` to `git commit -s`), but as it was already [answered](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias), that is not possible. The answer to my question has already been given. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

**upd Oct 2023: this is incorrect answer, please ignore**

---

You can use [commit.gpgSign option](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.9.5#Documentation/git-config.txt-commitgpgSign)

you can add it per repository by issuing the command below in the repo folder:

```
$ git config commit.gpgSign true
```

or for all git repository on your machine:

```
$ git config --global commit.gpgSign true
```

Comment: gpgSign is unrelated to the "sign-off" feature. "sign-off" feature is the lowercase "git commit -s" option, while gpgSign is the uppercase "git commit -S" option.

Comment: my bad, please disregard this answer